# Raspberry Piで、 Ruby のバージョンを確認しようとすると Illegal instruction が発生する

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, rbenv

Raspberry Pi で Raspbian を OS に使っています。

rbenv を用いてRuby 2.1.5 を入れていたのですが、 ruby のバージョンを確認しようとして

```
$ ruby -v
```

とすると、`Illegal instruction` と表示されてしまいます。

```
$ sudo ruby -v
```

で確認すると表示されるのですが、デフォルトで入っている ruby が表示されてしまいます

```
(ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [arm-linux-eabihf])
```

`$ rbenv versions` で確認したところ

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.1.5 (set by /home/pi/.rbenv/version)
```

と表示されるので、 2.1.5 はインストールされているみたいです。

この場合にどのようにして解決したら良いのかわからなかったので質問させて下さい。

ちなみに、

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo rpi-update
$ sudo reboot
```

は試してみたのですが変化ありませんでした

**【追記 2015/01/28】**

結局問題は解決しなかったので、

```
$ rbenv uninstall 2.1.5
```

で一旦アンインストールしてから再び入れなおしたら正常に動作しました。

Comment: そのrubyはRaspberry Pi上でコンパイルしたものでしょうか? `file /usr/bin/ruby` と `file ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby` を実行してみると何かヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: Raspberry pi上でコンパイルしたものです。
書き忘れてましたが、rubyは練習で動かしていたので既に動いていたのですが
確かrubygemsをインストールした後にこのような症状が出てしまったのではないかと思います

Comment: @YoheiK 自己解決された場合には、ご自身で解決策を回答として書いていただき、チェックマークを付けておいて頂けると、本質問が解決済みであることが他の回答者に分かります。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: @tomute さん
かしこまりました！

Comment: FYI: "Illegal instruction"が出たということは、実行ファイルが破損している or 別CPU向けの実行ファイルである のいずれかと考えられます。

Comment: @YoheiK 対応ありがとうございます。

Comment: @yohjpさん　遅くなりましてすみません！やっぱりファイルが破損しているのでしょうか、どうやっても解決できませんでしたので
再インストールで行いました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答というほどではないですが、解決した方法として
アンインストールを行いました

```
$ rbenv uninstall 2.1.5
```

で一旦アンインストールしてから

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.5
```

で再び入れなおしたら正常に動作しました。

Answer (score 0):

~/.bashrc もしくは ~/.bash_profile に

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

を追記してますか？

Comment: その設定が漏れていた場合rbenvコマンドが実行できないかrbenv環境下のrubyはPATHにないため起動できないという症状になると思いますが、Illegal Instructionが起きることがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 自分の環境で上記をコメントアウトしたところ、仰るとおり rbenv コマンドが実行出来ませんでした。失礼いたしました。

Comment: 返事が遅れました。
bash_profileに
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

は記述しているのです、、、、どこかライブラリが変わってしまったのでしょうか